# How to Get a Nested Array Field

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a table user which contains an array Employee which stores the names ,i need to retrieve the last element of the array.

Could not figure out.Tried with count but count gives value =1 but there are three elements in an array

r.table("user")("Employee").count()

I need count actual elements in Employee array which is 3.Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't call `.count` on a specific document's field, it will return the count of the sequence of documents. In your request, `1` as a result actually means there is one document in the table.

You need to loop over each document to fetch the last name for each document, and you can fetch it directly using `.nth`:

```
r.table("user").map(function(document) {
  return document.merge({lastName: document("Employee").nth(-1)});
  // or, if you like complicated stuff
  return {
    id: document('id'),
    lastName: document("Employee").nth(
      document("Employee").count().sub(1)
    )
  };
});
```